# Different Office Themes in Excel and Access

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

"Dark Gray" Office Theme appears too dark for me in Access, but it's completely OK in Excel and Word. Is there any way that I could use separate Office Themes for Access and Excel?

Comment: It's impossible, as the theme settings are apply to all Office apps.

Answer (score 0):

The Office 365 Theme is Office wide (all Office 365 apps). You will notice that Themes are under Account and not under Options.

So you will need to pick a Theme that is a compromise for you across all Office apps.